# What is the correct spelling of Bar chord?

Tags: terminology

Occasionally I respond to questions here, and I try to be correct in my answers, but in my literature and online investigations I've seen Bar-chord spelled or misspelled at least three different ways, Bar-chord, Barr chord, and Barre chord. Is each spelling acceptable or is one correct and the others incorrect?

Comment: I was being slightly jocular in my comments! Sad but true, there are those around who seem rather sensitive to what others may find amusing. Can't be too careful. Stay bland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In music, a **bar** is (in U.K. at least!) the name of a compartment in the written music, flanked by two **bar**lines.

**Barr** doesn't seem to exist as a word - although in the West Midlands there are Great Barr and Perry Barr districts in B'ham.

**Barre** is the one in most common use, often spelled with an acute accent over the e.

Comment: Huh I always imagined “barré” was pronounced in two syllables (~ “barray”). Funny that the pronunciation dropped a syllable but the accent was retained.